# Speed up Next.js / Vercel static build by caching the ajax calls

Tags: next.js, vercel

I recently ported my React site to Next.js and use Vercel hosting.

Every build, around 1500 routes are generated into a static page. I recently added 3 API calls to the static props of every page. The API calls are the same for every page and could perfectly be cached during the whole build process. While these API themselves have a good caching, it does make the Vercel build step take much longer than it did without the API calls. I am looking for the best way of achieving caching within Vercel build itself.

And it is not good enough to make some sort of npm script that pulls the API results locally to my computer before deploying manually because I use a cron job to build the entire site every X hours in Github tasks (as the API results are dynamic and do change over time).

Comment: if you want to change how you do things https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#fallback-true  https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#incremental-static-regeneration

Comment: This may be what you are looking for: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/10933

Comment: try using `SWR`